# PHP - Retrieve Access Token - Disable implicit OAuth

Tags: php, http, instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I'm using the Instagram Api.
To retrieve the access token, I use the method with the parameter 'code'.
From this code parameter, I can build a url which will returns me the access token.

Example :

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CODE_ID&redirect_uri=my-redirect-url&response_type=code
```

When I reach this URL through my web browser, after a redirection by Instagram, it returns to a web service I created. Then, my access token is stored.

How can I automatize this in PHP?

This example doesn't work:

```
exec('curl https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CODE_ID&redirect_uri=my-redirect-url&response_type=code');
```

How can I handle the redirection by Instagram?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to automate this since explicit user authentication is required before an authorization code is generated. So you'll have to redirect using PHP:

```
header('Location: https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CODE_ID&redirect_uri=my-redirect-url&response_type=code');
```

have the user authenticate in the browser to Instagram and then grab the code that is delivered to the `redirect_uri` by Instagram.